# Baked sweet potato french fries (chips) too soft, how to crispen?

Tags: french-fries

My first ever stab at french fries, and 20 minutes with olive oil and seasonings in the oven preheated at 450*F was not enough to make them crisp. They were cut thick.

Could I simply cook them longer to dry them up? They have the texture and consistency of a baked potato.... except the skins are crisp

Comment: Note that many "baked" french fries, as well as many "baked" potato chips, are actually fried, then baked.

Comment: Sounds like you made the kind of fries I like....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a few questions on this site about French fries, I'd suggest you take a look. But I think the best answer is: baked sticks of potato do not French fries make. French fries are deep fried. You can never get the same results in air, although air fryers do come close. A normal oven bakes, not fries.

Here are some sites that experiment with fries and crispiness [[1]](http://www.cookingissues.com/2010/04/27/the-quest-for-french-fry-supremacy-part-1/index.html) [[2]](http://aht.seriouseats.com/archives/2010/05/the-burger-lab-how-to-make-perfect-mcdonalds-style-french-fries.html).

Comment: Those links take Fries to the next level, thank you

Answer (score 9):

You can try a few things:

- dredge the fries in cornstarch (whack them in a plastic bag, give it a good shake), shake off the excess, then season.
- ensure the fries are in a single layer in the pan - crowding and stacking will mean they steam, not roast
- when they're nearly done, turn the oven off and leave them in there for 20 minutes or so before serving.

I would also avoid cutting them thick. They should be french fries, not steak fries.

Comment: +1 I completely agree about avoiding thick cuts for sweet potato fries. :3

Comment: The potatos were so hard to cut with a knife! I actually hurt my hand from the pressure on the handle. Am I doing something wrong? That's why I went thick -- after two potatoes my hands were red and I went back to programming computers.

Comment: +1: I make sweet potato wedges which are meant to be soft inside (according to me) but they're crispy on the outside because I dust them well with polenta (mixed with paprika, smoked paprika, cumin, thyme, black pepper...).  And cook them spread out in a single layer.

Comment: @JonathanLeaders A sharp knife and practice both help. Or you can upgrade to a mandolin-style slicer for better consistency and easier cutting.

Comment: @chris: polenta dusting is a great idea! I just made sweet potato fries from
the blog, smitten kitchen, substituting sweets for Yukon golds. They stuck to the aluminum foil; soggy, limp and was unhappy with the result. I am trying minimalist baker's website for crispier fries next!